# JSP Request and LinkedList

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, linked-list

I got an existing project in JSP but there is a little problem in showing database values.

The data is read correctly from database and stored into a LinkedList.
On click this data should be forwarded to the next page. 
The LinkedList is stored into the request attribute with `request.setAttribute(..)`.

When this attribute is read on the next page the last element of the list gets null. I am sure that all values are stored into the list.

I already tried to add an empty entry into the list but then the last 2 entries get null.

I think it can not be that problem but I am not able to figure it out.

Thank you guys and sorry for my stupid questions ;-)

Comment: My best advice is to run your web app in an IDE with a debugger, like IntelliJ.  Check what is populated and returned by the server.  Start up an HTTP sniffer like Fiddler and see what the traffic on the wire looks like.  Run your JSP in a browser with the developer console open so you can inspect the response returned.  You need information that SO can only guess at.

Answer (score 0):

You can either save the list as a session attribute, or pass as request parameters the info you need to repeat the query.

Comment: I already tried to store this into a session attribute but it's the same.

Comment: the very strange thing is that it works in other methods but only in this method it doesn't work.

Comment: nothing works. if i repeat the query in the same class it's the same problem